# Effective software scheduling

Tags: c, scheduler

For example in a code like below

```
while(1){
  task1();
  task2();
}
```

there should be cooperation between task1() and task2() which are executed in rr fashion. However, if task1() is implemented as follows

```
task1(){
  while(1);
}
```

Is there a way to build a scheduler which avoid monopolization of resources by task1() by only relying on software (for example switching tasks each 500 ms)?

Assume to have available only plain C/Assembly, and not rely on external scheduler/OS.

Comment: What processor?  I'm familiar with ARM and this is certainly possible.

Comment: Any processor. Could you link please some resources?

Comment: That's called *pre-emptive multi-tasking*, and it's usually achieved by using two *threads* or *processes*.

Comment: You can use a Real Time Operating System (RTOS) like FreeRTOS, Mbed OS etc. to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to build a scheduler which avoid monopolization of resources by task1() by only relying on software (for example switching tasks each 500 ms)?

Yes it's possible; but it probably isn't possible in plain C because (at a minimum) you'd need to switch between different stacks during task switches.

However, you should know that just switching tasks every 500 ms is very "not effective". Specifically; when one task has to wait for anything (time delay, data received from network, user input, data to be fetched from disk, a mutex, ...) you want to keep the CPU busy by switching to a different task (if there are any other tasks).

To do that; you either need fully asynchronous interfaces for everything (which C does not have), or you need to control all of the code (e.g. write an OS).

Of course the majority of task switches are caused by "task has to wait for something" or "something task was waiting for occurred"; and switching tasks every 500 ms is relatively irrelevant (it only matters for rare tasks that don't do any IO), and even when it is relevant it's a bad idea (in a "10 half finished jobs vs. 5 finished jobs and 5 unstarted jobs" way).

Comment: What do you mean by "it probably isn't possible in plain C"?  It would have to be written in assembly?

Comment: @FiddlingBits: Assembly would make it a lot easier; but (in theory, maybe; and being very dependent on the C library and being not portable at all) you might be able to use C to generate and manage `jmp_buf env` structure/s and then use (POSIX) `setjmp()` and `longjmp()` for the actual task switching.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `you either need fully asynchronous interfaces for everything`?   
Why Assembly would make it a lot easier? Can you give an example?

Comment: @AlbertoTiraboschi: For a synchronous interface (e.g. like "`read()`" in C) your task must wait for it to complete (e.g. wait for disk controller to fetch the data you wanted from a relatively slow hard disk). For an asynchronous interface it's more like you send a request and continue without waiting, and then (at some point in the future) you receive (possibly after polling) some kind of notification that your request was completed; and this (the "continue without waiting" part) allows software to not do any task switches for IO (and just do other things while its IO is happening).

Comment: @AlbertoTiraboschi: For high level languages, low level things (e.g. the contents of the flags register, instruction pointer, stack pointer) are abstracted, and there's no way to access or control them directly, and no way to save or load them. Assembly language gives you full control of all the low level things (e.g. it's easy to load a new value into the "stack pointer" register with a `mov rsp,...` instruction).

Comment: @Brendan, ok but even in Assembly it would not be possible to switch (in the general case) after a certain amount of time. For example suppose you have a task which contains a loop, that loops thousands of time, you would have for example to insert (proper assembly instructions) a timer in the loop body that checks the amount of time and then switches task. And this is a special case, for IO operations it would not be possible anyway. Am I thinking right?

Comment: @AlbertoTiraboschi: Yes - to avoid relying on a timer's IRQ; some software somewhere would need to check the time regularly and trigger the task switch at the right time. That could be code you explicitly write, or code that a compiler injected into your program without you knowing, or the OS using tricks (e.g. "trap on control flow changes" debugging facilities).

Answer (score 0):

one easy way is to use

1. a hardware timer,
2. a queue of tasks to run,
3. a scheduler
4. and a dispatcher.
5. a pre-allocated stack for each task

the timer interrupt handler triggers the scheduler. The scheduler determines which task is to run next. The scheduler triggers the dispatcher.
    The dispatcher performs a 'context' switch between the prior running task and the next task to run, placing the prior running task back into the queue, then restores the 'context' of the next task to run, then
    transfers execution control to the 'next' task,

The queue is composed of control blocks.  The control blocks contain a copy of all the registers and the address of the entry point for the task